# where is the output of print statement in apache-age code is printed?

Tags: postgresql, cypher, apache-age

I had made changes in the **apache-age** code, Now I want to confirm my changes
by using print statements. but when I use simple printf() it is not reflected
in the PostgreSQL log file.

But if I use the following piece of code in **apache-age** repo

```
ereport(WARNING, (errcode(ERRCODE_INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE),
                errmsg("Statement is %s",varname)));
```

then it reflects output in the PostgreSQL log as well as in the psql terminal,
But this also prints some additional warning statements with it.

[image]

**How can print simple statements without warnings?**

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the statements by giving them a WARNING status code. By using a different status code, you can print statements under some other log class.

You'll find the error codes used by postgres under the elogs.h header file. If you've used the default installation path for postgres, you'll find it under:

```
/usr/local/pgsql/include/server/utils/elog.h
```

Here are a few of the error codes defined under the file. You may find `NOTICE` useful for what you're trying to do.

```
/* Error level codes */
#define DEBUG5      10          /* Debugging messages, in categories of
                                 * decreasing detail. */
#define DEBUG4      11
#define DEBUG3      12
#define DEBUG2      13
#define DEBUG1      14          /* used by GUC debug_* variables */
#define LOG         15          /* Server operational messages; sent only to
                                 * server log by default. */
#define LOG_SERVER_ONLY 16      /* Same as LOG for server reporting, but never
                                 * sent to client. */
#define COMMERROR   LOG_SERVER_ONLY /* Client communication problems; same as
                                     * LOG for server reporting, but never
                                     * sent to client. */
#define INFO        17          /* Messages specifically requested by user (eg
                                 * VACUUM VERBOSE output); always sent to
                                 * client regardless of client_min_messages,
                                 * but by default not sent to server log. */
#define NOTICE      18          /* Helpful messages to users about query
                                 * operation; sent to client and not to server
                                 * log by default. */
#define WARNING     19          /* Warnings.  NOTICE is for expected messages
                                 * like implicit sequence creation by SERIAL.
                                 * WARNING is for unexpected messages. */
```

Answer (score 0):

ereport(DEBUG1, (errmsg("Statement is %s", varname)));